# How can I increase the font size in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

The font size in the editor in WebStorm is too puny for my taste (or my eyes, I should say).

I tried to change it via Settings > Editor > Colors & BFonts > Font, which does have a "Size" edit box in the "Editor Font" section, but it is readonly.

So how can I "up" the font size? I also (first) tried Ctrl+mouseWheel, but that didn't lead to any joy in Mudville, either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For change font and font size create your own theme, then you can edit all font things
[image]

Fonts color settings: be sure you uncheck inheritance checkbox with "use inheritance attributes"
[image]

P.s pictures from phpstorm but it must work for webstorm also

Comment: I can't express how ridiculous is the level of complexity of such a simple task as control font size. Just stupid. I could just leave this IDE right now.

Comment: This answer is now superceded by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44042665/261122

Answer (score 48):

**Change font size with MouseWheel**

(called "zooming in the editor")

> **To enable changing font size in the editor**
>
> 1. Open the Settings/Preferences dialog, expand the Editor node, and
>      click General.
> 2. Make sure that the setting Change font size (Zoom) with
>      Ctrl+MouseWheel is enabled.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/zooming-in-the-editor.html

Answer (score 15):

You need to save a custom scheme in order to modify the font size.

> Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts

Select `Save as...` and name it however you please.

Once you have saved your custom scheme, you are now able to increase the font size.

In Ubuntu, go to:

> File > Settings > Editor > Font

Answer (score 15):

File / Settings / General

Check "Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel

Confirmed fix for WebStorm 10.

Comment: Prefences -> Editor -> General for OS X

Comment: To change font size in **all files at once** you can also select `All editors` option (in the same menu), since `WebStorm 2022.1 (EAP)`.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Setting

[image]

Next In font you can change

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Actual for WS 2018.x

Change font-size for **interface**
[image: Change font-size for interface]

Change font-size for **code area**
[image]

Comment: did they remove the ability to change the interface font size?

Comment: jonnie no, Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Font

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for WebStorm version 2021.2.2

On the top right-hand side of the WebStorm editor you will see a setting gear icon as shown in the picture below or you can simply use the keyboard short cut `Ctrl+Alt+S`

[image]

After you tap on the setting option a window will open with all the different settings options, out of which you need to select the Editor option which will have the font option as shown in the image below

[image]

Now you can change the font as per your choice,

I am going to take a step ahead and include how you can increase the zoom size of the editor as well.

When I installed webstorm I was not able to increase the zoom via mouse wheel or by using the `Ctrl +` keyboard shortcut and this setting is in the same editor setting menu

So once you are inside the setting window go to `Editor > General` and in the general section you will find an option to increase the zoom via mouse wheel make sure you click apply or Ok once you select this option for the setting to take place

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To add something here for the developers using the Material Theme UI. Under the Editor => Font, you'll font a link, where you can make the actual font customizations under the section called "Editor > Color Scheme > Color Scheme Font." Just in case you won't be confused as me when changing the Editor > font size, nothing happens.
[image: Changing the font color]

[image: Color scheme font size]